# UWP ScrollViewer Left Header and ItemsPresenter

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I am trying to have a leftheader fixed in a scrollviewer but its height is not equal to the itemspresenter. I have given the code snippet.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              HorizontalSnapPointsType="Mandatory">
                <ScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
                    <Grid Width="190" Height="1000" Background="Black"/>
                </ScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
                <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

            </ScrollViewer>

        </ControlTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView">
            </ItemsStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Grid Width="1536" Height="1000" Background="Yellow"/>
        <Grid Width="1536" Height="1000" Background="Red"/>
        <Grid Width="1536" Height="1000" Background="Black"/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

You need to *scroll up* to see the [gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLUn.png).

Comment: They all appear to be with the same height as your code specifically set them all to `1000`.

Comment: It is expected to be of same height, but it doesnot appear to be same. The left header it taking the screen height. But I have give 1000 explicity.

Comment: yes it does. I am seeing them all with the same height. Straight copy from your code.

Comment: Sorry Justin, it is not working as expected for me. Not sure what is the problem. The code is shared is what iam also working on. But Left header "Black color Grid" appears to be in shorter height than other grids in the item control. Please scroll down and see for height difference @JustinXL

Comment: Oh... so you need to *scroll* to see that... My bad. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduce your issue. I will report this issue to the related team. Currently one workaround to fix the content of `LeftHeader` is that you could wrap the `Grid` with `Canvas` just like the following code .

```
<ScrollViewer.LeftHeader >
    <Canvas>
        <Grid Width="190" Height="1000" Background="Red" />
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks it saved my day.

Comment: If you still have any other question, please feel free to post here.

Comment: If you think this answer helps, please consider **accept** it.